# Линейный поиск в обероне-07

Tags: oberon, oberon-07

Из языка оберон-07 была убрана конструкция с `LOOP`
и `EXIT`.  Создатели пишут, что это сделано для того, чтобы
сделать язык более структурированным и убрать «скрытые
`GOTO`».  Как в таком случае проводить линейный поиск?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

([Взято с сайта *OberonCore.Ru*](https://oberoncore.ru/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B_%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2)).

Используется следующая конструкция:

```
i := 1;
WHILE ~(i > Last) & ~(Found(haystack[i], Needle)) DO
    i := i + 1
END;
IF ~(i > Last) THEN
    Out.String("found :-)");
ELSE
    Out.String("not found :-(");
END;
```

То есть, псевдокодом:

```
установка_начала_цикла();
ПОКА НЕ (конец_цикла()) И НЕ (найден_элемент()) ЦИКЛ
    следующая_ступень_цикла();
КОНЕЦ;
ЕСЛИ НЕ (конец_цикла()) ТО
    элемент_найден();
ИНАЧЕ
    элемент_не_найден();
КОНЕЦ;
```

Comment: мне кажется, в коде опечатка. Сперва идет установка счетчика, затем просто перебираем счетчик. При этом в цикле больше ничего не выполняется, а присвоение переменным, на основе которых выполняется проверка продолжения цикла, происходит **вне цикла**. То есть, цикл перебора счетчика никогда не остановится. Кмк, нужно условную конструкцию засунуть внутрь цикла.

Comment: @cauf  Не совсем понимаю вас.  Предполагается, что `Last` — последний индекс, а `Found()` — предикат на условие пойиска.  Соответственно, итерация закончится когда либо индекс выйдет за пределы коллекции, либо нужный элемент найден.

Answer (score 2):

Решение по исключению множественных неструктурных переходов -- верно. За редкими исключениями -- это даже плохо влияет на производительность, не говоря уже про логику. Примеры, когда можно сделать быстрее с неструктурным переходом можно найти у Кнута. Но я бы предпочёл всё же так не делать.
Линейный поиск правильно делать со специальным маркером продолжения цикла булева типа. Если требуются несколько вложенных циклов, то по рекомендации Стива МакКоннела из его известной книги -- надо вложенные циклы оформлять в виде отдельных процедур. Это и читабельней, и проще, и легче поддаётся тестированию в конце концов.

Answer (score 2):

Конкретный пример. Поиск числа в массиве.
Можно скомпилировать и запустить в системе Free Oberon.
(см. [freeoberon.su](https://freeoberon.su))

```
MODULE Ex;
IMPORT Out;

PROCEDURE Example*;
VAR m: ARRAY 100 OF INTEGER;
  i: INTEGER; (*бегунок по массиву*)
  x: INTEGER; (*что ищем*)
BEGIN
  (*Сначала как-то заполняется массив и x: *)
  m[6] := 23;
  x := 23;
  (*Затем ищем x в m: *)
  i := 0;
  WHILE (i # LEN(m)) & (m[i] # x) DO INC(i) END;
  (*после того, как цикл закончится,
    либо i будет равен LEN(m),
    либо m[i] будет равен x *)
  IF i # LEN(m) THEN
    (*фокус в том, что здесь непременно m[i] = x*)
    Out.String("Нашли x на позиции ");
    Out.Int(i, 0)
  ELSE
    Out.String("x не найден")
  END;
  Out.Ln
END Example;

BEGIN
  Example
END Ex.
```